# Calling SSL URL from Java gives certificate issues

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to do an API using SSL. When I perform the call, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://yyyyy.zzz/123":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I know there are many questions in StackOverflow regarding this issue, but the ones I saw was because certificate was self-signed. In this case certificate is valid and browser recognize it without problems as a valid one.

So my question is, why does it fail when calling from Java and it does work well when using the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue. The browser recognized the certificate (and certificate path), but Java Virtual Machine did not. The error text was the same.

In my case the trust root was in Browser keystore, and in Java trust keystore. So everyone could check thrust path. But if your server returns not the whole certificate path, but only server one, it is harder. In this case, the certificate path could be validated only if validator has the INTERMEDIATE certificate in its thrust-store.

Because the java keystore is not updated as regularly as these in browsers, you could have the intermediate certificate in browser, but not in JVM.

Possible solutions in this case:

- server to return the whole certificate chain
- the intermediate certificate to be added in java trust store

For more info check [Certificate path discovery in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974516/certificate-path-discovery-in-java)

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded the intermediate certificate and it works now.