# Java unable valid SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https

Bought several days ago SSL certificate. Chrome was working fine. Firefox few days was showing that not trust SSL certificate. But java throw errors like this:

```
Occurred error during authorization javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Http URL:

https://sessions.ensemplix.ru/auth/

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to add the CA certificate chain to the truststore. See this [question](https://superuser.com/q/55470) on superuser.com.

Update: used the much more precise terms of @EJP.

Comment: This is personal fix? Because this is launcher for players.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. What you mean is add the *CA certificate chain* to the *truststore.*

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. The browser recognized the certificate (and certificate path), but Java Virtual Machine did not. The error text was the same.

In my case the trust root was in Browser keystore, and in Java trust keystore. So everyone could check thrust path. But if your server returns not the whole certificate path, but only server one, it is harder. In this case, the certificate path could be validated only if validator has the INTERMEDIATE certificate in its thrust-store.

Because the java keystore is not updated as regularly as these in browsers, you could have the intermediate certificate in browser, but not in JVM.

Possible solutions in this case:

- server to return the whole certificate chain
- the intermediate certificate to be added in java trust store

For more info check [Certificate path discovery in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974516/certificate-path-discovery-in-java)

P.S. My Firefox thrusts your certificate??