# 2018 (March) Java SMTP TLS connections (only) from development (localhost) started failing -- production servers working

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, starttls

In development, which has worked for a few **years** now, we suddenly started to get SMTP certificate failures when trying to send email to either Mailgun (RackSpace) or AWS.

While we don't need to send a lot of mail from development but we do need to test some mail related activities from time to time.

Production seems to be working just fine and we've done some updates to production so it does not appear to be code/config related (but yes still could be I know...).

Production servers are a mix of latest AWS EC2 instances and RackSpace Linux servers whereas development is Mac based.

I suspect it is related to current industry upgrades in the SSL/TLS Certificate initiatives.

I have a huge stack trace but it's mainly Scala - the highlights appear to be:

```
Execution exception[[MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS]]

Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2155)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:620)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:547)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1351)

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

What I have done thus far (aside from scour google for a few days).

I have confirmed that I'm on the latest version of Java (Mac OS X -- Version 10.10.5) version 8 Update 161

I have confirmed that my app reports the version of Java as 1.8.0 implementation 25.0-b70

I do this by checking System Properties through the Runtime.

```
Java Runtime Environment version    1.8.0
Java Runtime Environment vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Virtual Machine specification version  1.8
Java Virtual Machine implementation version 25.0-b70
Java Virtual Machine implementation name    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

At the Terminal command line I get this:

```
mac-pro:~ me$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

I have updated the package com.sun.mail javax.mail to the latest version 1.6.1 and retested. Same symptoms.

I've tried explicitly declaring the cacerts path in  the startup of the app:

```
-DJAVA_CERT_PATH = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Of course I have reconfirmed that this file exists... (e.g. it did not get moved or relocated on an update)

```
mac-pro:~ me$ ls -lA /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel  82586  4 Mar  2014 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

If I use the keytool to examine it (which looks "normal" but I'm not the expert on what that should look like):

```
mac-pro:~ me$ keytool -list -v -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

I have tested from several apps/accounts all with the same issue.

Unsure where to go next. I've raised a ticket with one vendor and have essentially duplicated that ticket here to help others hitting this IF it's not something incredibly stupid I've done :)

Comment: If I check the date stamp for cacerts on an AWS linux server I see Feb 19 of this year. I thought the date of my cacerts file seems more than a little off. Doesn't appear to be much knowledge of how to get a replacement cacerts file yet either however as most ask you to import individual certs into an existing store not replace the ROOTs. I have seen something to the effect of go grab it from another server however and I'll see if that works or not.

Comment: Using a cacerts file from AWS Linux `/etc/pki/java/cacerts` with the `-DJAVA_CERT_PATH` pointing to it and I still get the same error. So that original file's age / contents might not be the problem.

Comment: Truly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975846/2162886 -- from which I found this gem: `Djavax.net.debug=all` from which I determined that there was a "break" between *my* `-DJAVA_CERT_PATH` and the actual cert file being used. The cert file I grabbed from the AWS linux box fixed the issue so the root cause of this **IS** a stale cacerts file.

Comment: The (my) actual JVM command line for using an alternate cacerts file is `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/awscacerts` truns out that I was using a `$SHELL_VARIABLE` which was picked up in an app that had special cert needs and did not pick that variable up in the apps I was presently testing. (That didn't help much...). Just posting this tidbit in case anyone else comes here scratching their head like I was...